# MyContractInstance.methods.MyMethod is not a function (Contract Instance cannot get contract methods) web3

Tags: ethereum, web3js

I am trying to implement ERC20 Token Contract using web3.js.
I created an instance of the contract, but when I am logging it in the browser console, I am not getting some of the later newly created methods.

The deployAddress and the abi are perfectly alright.

Here, is the code snippet, if anyone can help.

**Token contract**

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

import "/contracts/ERC20.sol";

contract YatharthaMudra is IERC20{
    
    string public symbol;
    string public name;
    uint public decimals;
    
    uint public __totalSupply;
    mapping(address => uint) private __balanceOf;
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint)) __allowances;

    constructor () public{
        symbol = "YMT";
        name = "Yathaartha Mudra";
        decimals = 18;
        __totalSupply = 1000*10**decimals;
        __balanceOf[msg.sender] = __totalSupply;
    }
    
    function getName() public view returns (string memory){
        return name;
    }
    
    function getSymbol() public view returns (string memory){
        return symbol;
    }
    
    function getDecimal() public view returns (uint){
        return decimals;
    }
    
    function totalSupply()external view override returns (uint _totalSupply){
        _totalSupply = __totalSupply; 
    }
    
    function balanceOf(address _addr) public view override returns(uint _balanceOf){
        return __balanceOf[_addr];
    }
    
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) external override returns (bool _success){
        //require instead of if
       if(_value <= __balanceOf[msg.sender]&&
       _value > 0){
        __balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;
        __balanceOf[_to] += _value;
        return true;
       }
       return false;
    }
    
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) external override returns (bool _success){
        if(__allowances[_from][msg.sender] > 0 &&
        _value > 0 &&
        __allowances[_from][msg.sender] >= _value &&
        __balanceOf[_from] >= _value){
            __balanceOf[_from] -= _value;
            __balanceOf[_to] += _value;
            __allowances[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    
     function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) external override returns (bool _success){
        __allowances[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
            return true;
        
    }
    
    function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) external view override returns (uint256 _remaining){
        return __allowances[_owner][_spender];
    }
}
```

**index.js(web3.js)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(!window.ethereum){
        alert("Please install Metamask!");
    }
    else{
        window.web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
        console.log("Metamask connected");
        console.log(window.ethereum);

        web3.eth.net.getId().then(console.log);
        web3.eth.getAccounts().then(function(accounts){
            let account = accounts[0];
            web3.eth.getBalance(account).then(function(balance){
                let balance1 = web3.utils.fromWei(balance);
                console.log(balance1+" ETH");
            });
        });

        var abi = /* abi here */

        var contractAddress = /* contract deploy address here */
        var YTMTokenContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, contractAddress);

        console.log(YTMTokenContract);
        YTMTokenContract.methods.getName().call(function(token_name){
            console.log(token_name);
            tokenSupply.innerHTML = token_name[enter image description here][1];
        }).catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        });

        YTMTokenContract.methods.totalSupply().call(function(total_supply){
            console.log(total_supply);
            tokenSupply.innerHTML = total_supply;
        }).catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
        
    }
});
```

**Output in the console:**
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXJNJ.jpg

Actually, some of my contract methods are not visible, so I cannot access them although I created the contract Instance.

Any answers to why this happens?>>>

Comment: Please have the output as the part of the question body, as screenshots are unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer.
I was using the ABI of erc20.sol and not of the *token.sol*.
Thankyou!